# Why use @property in D?

Tags: properties, d

I figured out by trying that

```
struct PropertyTest
{
    @property int x() { return val; }
    @property void x( int newVal ) { val = newVal; }

    void test()
    {
        int j;
        j = x;
        x = 5;
    }

private:
    int val;
}
```

does exactly the same when I leave the `@property` out. Everything compiles fine. What's the point then for declaring functions as `@property`?

BTW, I'm using the dmd2 compiler.

Comment: At the moment the compiler is more permissive than it may be in the future.  Marking getters and setters with @property is a good way to future proof.  To see what the future may be like, compile with -property.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason they work without `@property` is because `@property` was added after they allowed the property method syntax.  Adding `-property` to your DMD command line enforces use of `@property` annotation.  It's not the default for backward compatibility reasons.  Someday it will become the default (or so they say) so it's best to compile with `-property` to ensure you are annotating properly.

Answer (score 1):

It lets you use a no-arg method without parentheses (like reading a variable), and it lets you call a single-arg method without parentheses, the way you assign to a variable.

```
@property int foo() { ... }
@property void bar(int x) { ... }

void main()
{
    bar = foo;
}
```

You should specify `-property` as a command line option for the compiler.